# shall I load scene data directly into video memoy

Tags: memory, graphics, 3d, gpu

I'm currently working on loading 3D scene data (vertices and faces) for a mobile game.

My first thought was to load all data into system memory, and transfer only visible parts into video memory while traveling in scene.

I learned that in mobile, system memory and video memory both share the same memory. I thought it might be better to load all scene data into video memory directly, because no transferring is needed when traveling in the scene, Am I right?

Comment: Can we have an idea of the amount of 3D data needed by your game in a single level (number of polygons / size in MB of the data ...) ?

Comment: Does it matter how much data per level? wheather load it into system memory or video memory,they sit in the same physical memory card.
to my knowledge, only the sum of system and memory video memory matters.

Comment: I asked because if your game is not a big open world, then the usual way of doing it is to load everything in video memory (so textures, vertex buffers & index buffers) during the level loading screen and avoid loading anything during level playing as this will cause little freezes (except if you do it properly by using threads and a shared GLES context). 
Also most of the time the game data is compressed to reduce game installed size, so the usual path is : read from disk and uncompress into system memory then upload to video memory and finally free the system memory.

Comment: My scene is not a big open world,your advice is very suitable for my situation,and is exactly what i want to know,many thanks.